# Bitnami Djangostack + Eclipse IDE?

Tags: django, eclipse, bitnami

I'm trying to setup the Eclipse (with pyDev) to work with Bitnami Djangostack in Mac OS X. I have installed the Djangostack and it works all right.

Problem is that I can't get the Eclipse to understand Djangostack. I've added the Djangostack  python interpreter to the PyDev-setup. And also I added the apps/django folder to the Libraries. apps/django folder exist in the djangostack folder. Still, when I'm trying to create PyDev Django project, Eclipse cannot find Django (import django do not work). Any ideas what other things I'd have to setup before Eclipse can find the Djangostack installation?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it cannot find the django package.

Make sure you're adding it to the PYTHONPATH.

i.e.:
if it's installed at:

```
/foo/bar/django
/foo/bar/django/__init__.py
```

make sure that /foo/bar/ is in your interpreter PYTHONPATH (and make sure that /foo/bar/django is NOT in the PYTHONPATH).